# Firebase cloud function logs 'Error: incorrect function response. Function invocation was interrupted.'

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a website with 2 links. One to download an MP3 and one to download a WAV file

**For example:**

`<a href="https://mywesbite.com/download?file=//assets.net/beethoven-fur-elise.wav" download="beethoven-fur-elise">Download WAV</a>`

and

`<a href="https://mywesbite.com/download?file=//assets.net/beethoven-fur-elise.mp3" download="beethoven-fur-elise">Download MP3</a>`

I have written a cloud function for /download/ which will send the remote audio file so the user will be prompted to download the file and not have it open in a new tab and play.

The **MP3** link works but the **WAV** file fails and the error logs show this

```
Error: incorrect function response. Function invocation was interrupted.
Function execution took 2941 ms, finished with status: 'response error'
```

Please note that on my local machine both WAV & MP3s work.

The `MP3` files are around **3-6 MB**

The `WAV` files are around **40 MB**

## Firebase Cloud function

```
const express = require('express');
const request = require('request');
const cors = require('cors');
const helmet = require('helmet');

const downloadApp = express();

downloadApp.use(helmet());
downloadApp.use(
  cors({
    origin: true
  })
);

downloadApp.get('/download', (req, res) => {
  res.set(
    'Cache-control',
    `public, max-age=${CONFIG.TIME.CACHE_IN_USERS_BROWSER}, s-maxage=${
      CONFIG.TIME.CACHE_IN_CDN
    }`
  );

  /**
   *
   * contentType = 'audio/wav'
   *          OR
   * contentType = 'audio/mpeg'
   *
   * */

  res.setHeader('Content-Type', contentType);
  res.setHeader('Content-disposition', `attachment; filename="${filename}"`);

  // External URL to MP3 or WAV
  const externalUrl = 'https://external-website.com/something.wav';

  request
    .get(externalUrl)
    .on('error', function(err) {
      console.error('Download Error: ', err);
    })
    .pipe(res);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I was faced with a somewhat similar issue, and eventually figured the failure had to do with the quotas and limits described [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas).

All my cloud functions failed for responses > 10MB.

Comment: Ah, Yesssss. Thanks for letting me know. I eventually found this document website but forgot to update the status. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Functions quotas:

Max uncompressed HTTP response size  = 10MB per invocation

Max uncompressed HTTP request size = 10MB per invocation